# Can't change the list-style-type of a ::marker

Tags: css

Switching out the list-style-type doesn't seem to do anything for a ul li ul li. Not sure if it's possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/swfkmo9t/

```
<ul>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li>this is a test</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

ul li ul li::marker{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::marker` is a pseudo with a limited set of properties, not an element with `list-style` property. Use simply `ul li ul li {`
Read more on: [::marker - Allowable Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#allowable_properties)

```css
ul li ul li {
  list-style: square;
}

ul li ul li::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>this is a test</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your css is don't give `list-style-type` property to `::marker`. Give the `list-style-type` property to the `li` tag.

```css
ul li ul li{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li>this is a test</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```